# How to store a name in a cookie and echo it?

Tags: php, cookies, echo

Alright so what I am doing is I have a Text box and submit button that posts to the current page. The user can put their name in it.
It creates a cookie and that cookie will echo out their name on the page after they pressed submit.

But I can't seem to do this in one page refresh.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$post = $_POST["fname"]; 

$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", $post, $expire);

echo $_COOKIE["user"];
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post all the code instead you are using?

Comment: Updated it with all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the `$_COOKIE` or `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` array:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
       $post = $_POST["fname"]; 

       $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
       setcookie("user", $post, $expire);
      header("Location: index.php"); //notice the redirect?
    }
 ?>

<form action="" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
   <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
   echo $_COOKIE["user"];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` because this is deprecated. In you example you use `$_COOKIE` wat is correct.

Answer (score 1):

cookie should be set before outputting any content (html)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST['fname'){
    $post = $_POST["fname"]; 

    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie("user", $post, $expire);

    echo $_COOKIE["user"];
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How come this answer is accepted? You cannot SET and ECHO cookie without page refresh

Answer (score 1):

Try this code I also add some checks:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'post' && isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname'])) {
$post = $_POST["fname"]; 

$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", $post, $expire);
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
} else {
echo 'There is no firstname.';
}
?>
```